# Missing network list in menubar after using airmon-ng

Tags: networking, kali-linux, airmon-ng

After using airmon-ng in kali linux the list of available networks is missing in the menu bar at the top. Can anyone please tell me how to "reactivate" it?

When i use iwconfig it shows up an entry for wlan0

```
Mode: changed
Access point: not associated
RTS thr: off
Fragment thr: off
enc key: off
power management: off

lo -> no wireless connection
eth0 -> no wireless connection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to end the monitor mode you created.

`sudo airmon-ng stop mon0`

I would also assume that you killed any processes that airmon complained about upon starting your monitor interface. So you need to restart network manager and any other processes you killed.

`sudo service network-manager start`

as well as starting any other services you stopped or running any other commands that you killed after your airmon-ng start command.

**EDIT:**  A good old restart usually does the trick if you cant remember everything you did.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you must know i run kali from a pendrive and of course a restart did the job but i thought maybe there is a smoother way than doing so. i already tried stopping mon mode but got a input/output error every time i tried. i tried `service network-manager start` now but got the same i/o error. now.

Comment: What is the error its giving you?  I would assume this is the root cause of your problem

Comment: the error at which point? after using airmon mode and quitting it, the symbol for network connections at the top menu is not visible anymore and i try to bring it back. i also couldnt start other processes and so i thought maybe its an "error" from my kali installation because i burnt it on a pen drive.

Comment: What is the input/output error you get when you try to stop monitor mode and when you try to restart network-manager?

Comment: at that point is no error when i type `airmon-ng stop mon0` i get a list of interfaces including only wlan0 (mon mode off). then, when i type in `service network-manager start` i get the error message: unable to execute /usr/sbin/service: Input/Output error

Comment: Please execute the command `mkdir test` and let me know if there is the same error or not. It sounds like perhaps there is an issue with the Kali ISO image or something went wrong when you burned the ISO to the usb drive.  Execute that and let me know what happens please

Comment: no, there is no error but when i try to access drive "file system" from file browser i could not access. the folder is created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21972/discussion-between-dylan-and-brainworx).

Comment: thanks a lot, ive burnt the image with UNetBootin and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kali Linux just type `NetworkManager`, this command will bring the interface back.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by typing:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager force-reload
```